# Worksheet activate event is not firing despite other events working

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in a worksheet named "DTR-MR" and I have a `Worksheet Activate` event that dose not fire if I switch to the worksheet like it should. The code is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DTR-MR").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="stamping123123123"
End Sub
```

Similarly, another worksheet that locks the worksheet on activation also doesn't activate as shown below:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="stamping123123123"
End Sub
```

However, other `Worksheet Activate` events in the worksheet fire the code inside with no problem. The code inside the bugged events works because if I manually run the code, or step through the code (F8) the worksheet is locked.

Comment: Could it be any of your procedures did a `Application.EnableEvents = False` ? If that is the case, no events will be fired.

Comment: @Damian Nope none at all. Also the odd thing is that some events work with no problem but these 2 don't work. Even another worksheet that uses the same event and code, works when I press that worksheet

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet` instead `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR")` and see if it works?

Comment: @Damian No improvement upon changing it. I believe the code inside is working it's the event which is not firing since if I step through the code, it works. The event is highlighted when I step through it and it works with no issue. But simply activating the worksheet does not fire it

Comment: Try to add a line `MsgBox "This is working"` to see if it does.

Comment: Oh it works. That's odd but when I step the code, it protects but doesn't when event fired. So event does work, but the code inside doesn't work when event is fired, but works when stepped through

Comment: If it works, the event is firing, so the problem is on the code. Now you have your lead :)

Comment: What's wrong with it though? It works when I step through or press the run module. It's like working and not working??

Comment: It is working for me... I can't tell what is wrong, could be some configuration, try it out on a clean new workbook. If it does... I'd consider to move all your stuff to the new workbook.

Comment: Try to use `Sheets()` instead of `Worksheets()`

Comment: @Rawrplus You mean `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTR-MR").Protect`? It doesn't work as well

Comment: Yeah I did,. But that's odd, because it should work. Are you sure you're checking for what you have to / understand when `Worksheet_Activate` is fired?

Comment: Yes pretty sure cause when I run module or step through the sheet gets locked. But otherwise, it's still unlocked. Might as well just transfer everything to a new workbook as suggested. But will have to recreate the tables and all. Odd thing about VBA there are times it works for a long time then suddenly gives out. Trying out codes such as `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pay-MR").Cells(10, 10) = "Hello"` works in the event activation so probably something to do with the protect. Even a simple `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pay-MR").Protect` is completely bugged out in the event